# Output Array Items

Tags: php, database, arrays, salesforce, soql

I'm using Salesforce.com Toolkit for PHP and I'm trying to output something I think is very simple.

THIS IS WORKING EXAMPLE CODE

```
$query = "SELECT ID, Phone FROM Contact LIMIT 5";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
echo $record->ID." - ".$record->Phone;
}
```

I'VE TWEAKED THE QUERY AND NOW WANT TO JUST OUTPUT THE NAME AND THE COUNT. HOWEVER THE CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK

```
$query = "SELECT owner.name, count(type) FROM Task LIMIT 5";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
echo $record->owner.name; //DOES NOT WORK
}
```

THIS IS WHAT I GET WHEN I **print_r ($record);**

```
stdClass Object ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [0] => First Last [1] => 2177 ) )
```

I just want to be able to output "First Last - 2177"

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT ME?!?!?!?! :@

Comment: Haha, sorry for the misuse of caps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($response->records as $record)
{
    echo implode(' - ', $record->any);
}
```

Comment: Alix, If I wanted to get just the first name or just the count. How would I do that without implode?

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w: I *knew* you were going to ask that! :P Try `echo $record->any[0]` and `echo $record->any[1]`.

Comment: You saved my day! I promise to make better use of caps next time :)

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w: Actually for the *first* name is a bit harder. `$name = array_filter(explode(' ', $record->any[0]), 'strlen'); $name_first = $name[0]; $name_last = $name[count($name) - 1];`.